# How can I set values at multiple memory locations, atomically?

Tags: cuda, atomic

the CUDA Programming Guide said that any atomic operation can be implemented using `atomicCAS()`, and gives an example of atomic double add:

```
__device__ float single(double *address,double val)
{
unsigned long long int *address_as_ull =(unsigned long long int*)address;
unsigned long long int assumed;
unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull;

do
{
    assumed = old;
    old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull,assumed,__double_as_longlong(val + __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
}while(assumed !=old);
   return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
```

now,I face the problem that:

I want to write a function that can operate two variables address atomically.

**for example:**
atomic add about two variable

input

```
double *address_1, int *address_2
double val_1,int val_2
```

result

```
*address_1 = *address_1+val_1;
*address_2 = *address_2+val_2;
```

how can I deal with the problem? thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with calling the atomic addition function twice? From the description in your question, the two operations are independent.

Comment: here is an simple example, actually in this case do the operation twice is ok ~ but in my situation, i need the atomic function with two address. do you have any suggestion? thanks~

Comment: Nothing like that exists

Comment: I think using a structure to store the two variable may be help. you see the double is transfer into ull, but I have no idea how to deal with the unsigned long long int and structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you cannot do this. The hardware does *not* support atomic changes to multiple locations in memory. While you can circumvent this if both variables are small enough to fit into the size of a single atomic operation - this approach will fail if you have more than 8 bytes overall. You will encounter the ["too much milk"](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~emery/classes/cmpsci377/f07/scribe/scribe8-1.pdf) problem.

One thing you could do is have some kind of *synchronization protocol* for accessing these two values. For example, you could use a mutex, which only one thread can obtain, to safely know that nobody else is changing the values while that thread is working on them. See: [Avoid taking a long time to finish the 'too much milk' scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584828/avoid-taking-a-long-time-to-finish-the-too-much-milk-scenario).

Of course, this is quite expensive in a GPU setting. You had probably better do one of the following (by increasing order of favorability):

- Use a pointer or an index into a larger array, and instead of changing the structure atomically, switch the pointer atomically. This resolves the concurrency issue, but makes accesses slower.
- Change your algorithm so that accesses can be separated and don't have to happen atomically.
- Change your algorithm further, to avoid having multiple threads writing to a single complex data structure.

Comment: Thanks you for your clarity~ The material you attached really helped me~

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the point of the operation implemented here. In `a+=b`, the logical operation is `a = a + b`, but with CAS you avoid spurious changes to `a` between its read and its write. `b` is used once and not a problem.

In `a = b + c`, none of the values appear twice, so there's no need to protect against any changes in between.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want to write a atomic code which can modify two variables atomically. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: thank you for your clarify~ now i have the solution~

Answer (score 0):

thanks all the guys reply me!
I now have the solution.
we can combine the two variable into a structure. so we can transfer "two variable with two address" into "one structure with one address". here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct pair_t
{
    float x;
    int y;
};

__device__ float single(double *address,double val)
{   

    unsigned long long int *address_as_ull =(unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int assumed;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull;

    do
    {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull,assumed,__double_as_longlong(val + __longlong_as_double(assumed)));
    }while(assumed !=old);
    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}



__device__ void myadd(pair_t *address, double val_1 ,int val_2)
{   
    union myunion
    {  
        pair_t p;
        unsigned long long int ull;
    };

    unsigned long long int *address_as_ull;
    address_as_ull = (unsigned long long int *)address;

    union myunion assumed;
    union myunion old_value;
    union myunion new_value;

    old_value.p = *(pair_t *)address_as_ull;

    do
    {
        assumed = old_value;
        // cirtical area begin--------------------
        new_value.p.x = assumed.p.x+val_1;
        new_value.p.y = assumed.p.y+val_2;
        // cirtical area end----------------------

        old_value.ull = atomicCAS(address_as_ull,assumed.ull,new_value.ull);
    }while(assumed.ull !=old_value.ull);
}


__global__ void kernel (pair_t *p)
{
    myadd(p,1.5,2);
}

int main()
{
    pair_t p;
    p.x=0;
    p.y=0;
    pair_t *d_p = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((pair_t **)&d_p, sizeof(pair_t));
    cudaMemcpy(d_p, &p, sizeof(pair_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<100, 100>>>(d_p);

    cudaMemcpy(&p, d_p, sizeof(pair_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    printf("x=%lf\n", p.x);
    printf("y=%d\n", p.y);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

and the solution is

```
x=15000.000000
y=20000
```

now everything will be ok~

Comment: 1. This is convoluted. You don't have to go through doubles at all. 2. More generally - this only works since the total size of the structure is small enough for you to act on it atomically.